# Simple HTML DOM parser in PHP

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm using `simple_html_dom.php` to get values from the html.

```
<?php
// Create a DOM object; You must do this for each way
include('dom/simple_html_dom.php');
// Load HTML from a string
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('test.html');
$reasoncode = $html->find('input[name=reasonCode]');

foreach($reasoncode as $e){
    $results[] = $e->value;
}
?>
```

In the above code, if I print the `$results[]`, it returns the correct value that I need. But if I print `$reasoncode` , it prints a long html object array and runs in an infinite loop.

Comment: How do you determine that it runs in an infinite loop, what happens exactly?

Comment: I'm a beginner in PHP DOM parser. I printed it annowingly. So what.

Comment: Fair enough, but what is your end goal with the code?

Comment: @Pekka - My browser becomes not responding.

Comment: @Pekka - I wanna know what's happening in the backend. I'm trying to learn the functions in the simple_html_dom.php

Comment: Does the browser stop responding after the HTML has been output, or while trying to output it? How big is it? Maybe it overflows because the HTML is invalid, can you try validating it?

Comment: With respect to Simple HTML DOM, if you're just starting out, I encourage you to learn the native [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) library.

Comment: No. I'm not sure about that. But the output is printed and the browser still loading.

Comment: @Jason - Ofcourse. I'm trying to learn.